# javascript drop down bug

Tags: javascript

There are here 2 dropdown selects in the product.
I can choose either one without a problem, but can then not choose the second one (does not matter which one is choosen first.)
I'm sure this is something simple......if i only new what it was :-)

http://keith464.fahrradhamburg.de/Lager/Metall-Behaelter/Stahlblech-Behaelter/Stapelbehaelter-aus-Stahlblech.html

Comment: I think you are re creating the drop down.Since it is not native html drop down you need to reattach events again.

Comment: so can anyone please help here

Comment: I checked your page in it is working in FF but throwing some exception on dropdown selection in Chrome. you should check error in console. you can enable your drop down by re running $('div.dropDown p').oxDropDown(); after drop down selection. But I think You don't require this code to rerun after fixing your bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well for me it wasn't working in any browser.

But after a lot of searching, have solved the problem.
Someone had unfortuntaly added a css class to an id !

So the jquery was trying to write to the id #prodinfo
which no longer existed, as it was now #prodinfo column

- that was fun to debug !